# How to find the indexPath of a custom cell, when the cell contains a specific item?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

I have a custom cell containing several items, including a name and age.

In another view controller, in the viewDidLoad, I set the cell with specific names etc.

In viewDidDisappear, I would like to know what is the age for the name "X".

However I have no reference to the cell whatsoever, and I am trying to find out what is the indexPath of the cell containing name "X" to get its corresponding age value.

I have stumbled upon this:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: <#Int#>, inSection: <#Int#>)
```

In order to use this:

```
let cell: customCellTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! customCellTableViewCell
```

This is how I set up cellForRowATIndexPath:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell: customCellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCellTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row


    let memb = self.arrayMemb[indexPath.row]

    cell.setCell(memb.name, age: memb.age)

    return cell

}
```

And the I would be able to proceed. 
However I do not know how to get the NSIndexPath based on the name value "X".

Any idea how to do this,
Thank you infinitely,

Comment: How do you set the value of the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? You have to use the same logic to create the `NSIndexPath` and suggest to search in your datasource model the info instead of each cells.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question with cellForRowAtIndexPath. Could you precise how to do the search in the datasource please ?

Comment: Search the index (if it exists) of "X" in `self.arrayMemb`, then you can call: `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:theIndexFound, inSection:0)`

Comment: You got it! Thanks a lot. How can I accept your answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name, get the member from the data source (model) rather than from the cell (view)

The code assumes that `memArray` contains a member with the given name in any case.

```
let givenName = "John Doe"

let filteredMembers = memArray.filter {$0.name == givenName}
let age = filteredMembers[0].age
```